# azure web site deploy empty

Tags: silverlight, azure

I have created a website in AZURE and deployed my simple Silverlight website.

The deploy has worked but the website presents a standard Microsoft 'there is nothing here' graphic.

I have tried to use the FTP host name details to view the site, but my deployment credentials do not work either.

Any ideas why the website thinks that it is empty?

Comment: I guess this is because your solution and project structure is not valid, or not recognized by azure website kudu engine. Maybe you would have another try for default project structure for example create a new ASP.NET Web Application with Sliverlight. Ref your FTP login problem you can reset your credential in the portal and have another try.

Comment: Have you tried entering the full path to your aspx 'start' file? They are nearly never called 'index' or 'default', so just try entering the full path and see if that still produces a 'nothing there' error. e.g. `http://yourazurewebsite.com/somefilename.aspx`

Comment: Thanks Mashton, that works fine. Adding the .aspx file to the url made it work.

Comment: Also the Azure deployment credentials are for all your deployments on that Azure account so you have to pre fix the website name to your deployment user name in FTP and then it works fine as well. e.g yourazurewebsite/username. Thanks for all your help.